# How can I overlap transfer data with executing Thrust algorithms?

Tags: parallel-processing, cuda, gpgpu, thrust

I use (CUDA C++) Thrust for GPU GeForce GTX 460SE with asyncEngineCount = 1.
As I know I can overlap transfer data one of way to/from GPU and executing single kernel. But when I use:

```
cudaStream_t Stream1, Stream2;
cudaStreamCreate(&Stream1);
cudaStreamCreate(&Stream2);
cudaMemcpyAsync(thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_vec_src.data()), host_ptr1, test_size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice, Stream1);
cudaMemcpyAsync(host_ptr2, thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_vec_dst.data()), test_size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost, Stream2);
thrust::sort(d_vec_dst.begin(), d_vec_dst.end());
cudaThreadSynchronize();
```

and Thrust algorithms, it executes sequentially as I see in nVidia Visual Profiler: transfer from GPU, transfer to GPU, executing kernel. Maybe this is because Thrust algorithms executing in zero 0-stream which can't overlap with anything? And how solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thrust doesn't presently have a mechanism for controlling the execution stream of its algorithms, so you can't do what you are asking with the current code base. There have been reports of users modifying the thrust code base to accept a stream (for example [this google groups thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/?fromgroups#!topic/thrust-users/zva0W8bqZF0)) but that may or may not be viable depending on the complexity of the algorithm you use and its structure. Some algorithms also have internal data transfers and you would need to be very careful to not break things when moving from serial to asynchronous execution.

Comment: But then I have to change every next version of Thrust :) 
As I understand it, the main problem is that the algorithms (Thrust) run at zero-stream. And in this case, if i don't change Thrust, will not it help me, if I launch to asynchronous coping (cudaMemcpyAsync) of data in parallel  in a separate CPU thread?

Comment: No. Contexts can't be simultaneously shared by multiple host threads. As I already said, thrust doesn't support this and you can't get around this limitation without writing your own code (equivalenly modifying thrust yourself). Thrust was designed for convenience and ease of use, not ultimate performance.

Answer (score 4):

For anyone still searching, I believe Thrust now [supports streams.](https://github.com/thrust/thrust/blob/7b1d84e1bf75fc3f60d01058e3f008ef94bb7b28/testing/backend/cuda/sort.cu)

```
cudaStream_t s;
cudaStreamCreate(&s);
thrust::sort(thrust::cuda::par(s), keys.begin(), keys.end());
cudaStreamSynchronize(s);
cudaStreamDestroy(s);
```

Edit: I think the syntax has now been changed to `thrust::cuda::par.on(s)` in the latest commits.